# Semantic difference between `\amalg` and `\coprod` for disjoint union

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols, semantics

What's the semantic difference between `\amalg` and `\coprod` for disjoint unions?

I used to use `\amalg` for binary operations like `X \amalg Y` and `\coprod` for operators like `\coprod_\lambda X_\lambda`. But I realized that I don't know any literature or manual how these similar-looking symbols should be used. Please tell me if you have any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer by myself soon after I asked a question. To close this question, I write an answer by myself.

In a document in https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive, `\amalg` appears in "Table 50: Binary Operators" among `\cup`, `\oplus` and `\setminus`. On the other hand, `\coprod` appears in "Table 72: Variable-sized Math Operators" among `\bigcup`, `\bigoplus` and `\sum`. So these symbols should be used exactly as I described in the question.

Comment: One can see from `\coprod_0^n` in both textstyle and displaystyle that it behaves in the manner of `\sum`.  In contrast, `\amalg` does not change size/limit-style in displaystyle.  As a binary operator, it behaves in the manner of `+` and `-`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the difference between their behavior. The _real_ problem (led me to ask) is that I often annoyed when `\coprod` is used as a binary operator (but I don't have sound reasons for refusing). It would be better than my answer if there is some literature pointing out this as a common mistake.

Comment: What is `\amalg` short for?

Comment: I believe it's short for _amalgam_.